# Asignar valores a una columna DataFrame. Phyton

Tags: python

Quiero asignar en mi DataFrame valores a una columna en base a una condición

Mi data frame es:

```
a fecha1 fecha2
1 5/5/2018 11:00:00   25/5/2018  16:00:00
2 25/10/2018 10:00:00   15/5/2018  12:00:00
1 15/4/2018 12:00:00   14/9/2013  12:00:00
3 7/11/2017 19:00:00   30/6/2018  19:00:00
4 3/6/2015 17:00:00   31/4/2013  17:00:00
1 9/12/2012 13:00:00   16/5/2014  11:00:00
```

Se trataría de que cuando `a=1`, `fecha2` tiene que sustituir a `fecha1` quedando

```
a fecha1 fecha2
1 25/5/2018  16:00:00   25/5/2018  16:00:00
2 25/10/2018 10:00:00   15/5/2018  12:00:00
1 14/9/2013  12:00:00   14/9/2013  12:00:00
3 7/11/2017 19:00:00   30/6/2018  19:00:00
4 3/6/2015 17:00:00   31/4/2013  17:00:00
1 16/5/2014  11:00:00   16/5/2014  11:00:00
```

Comment: Yo mismo me contesto:
df.loc[df.a==1, ['fecha1']]=['fecha2']

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas, te aporto mi granito de arena:

1.- Creo que la fecha 31/4/2013  17:00:00 tendría que ser 30/4/2013  17:00:00

2.- Aquí mi código usado para reproducir y solucionar el problema:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1], 'fecha1': [datetime(2018, 5, 5, 11), 
 datetime(2018, 10, 25, 10), datetime(2018, 4, 15, 12), datetime(2017, 11, 7, 19),
 datetime(2015, 6, 3, 17), datetime(2012, 12, 9, 13)], 'fecha2': [datetime(2018, 5, 25, 16),
 datetime(2018, 5, 15, 12), datetime(2013, 9, 14, 12), datetime(2018, 6, 30, 19), 
 datetime(2013, 4, 30, 17), datetime(2014, 5, 16, 11)]})
df
Out:
   a              fecha1              fecha2
0  1 2018-05-05 11:00:00 2018-05-25 16:00:00
1  2 2018-10-25 10:00:00 2018-05-15 12:00:00
2  1 2018-04-15 12:00:00 2013-09-14 12:00:00
3  3 2017-11-07 19:00:00 2018-06-30 19:00:00
4  4 2015-06-03 17:00:00 2013-04-30 17:00:00
5  1 2012-12-09 13:00:00 2014-05-16 11:00:00

df.loc[df.a==1, 'fecha1'] = df.loc[df.a==1, 'fecha2']
df
Out:
   a              fecha1              fecha2
0  1 2018-05-25 16:00:00 2018-05-25 16:00:00
1  2 2018-10-25 10:00:00 2018-05-15 12:00:00
2  1 2013-09-14 12:00:00 2013-09-14 12:00:00
3  3 2017-11-07 19:00:00 2018-06-30 19:00:00
4  4 2015-06-03 17:00:00 2013-04-30 17:00:00
5  1 2014-05-16 11:00:00 2014-05-16 11:00:00
```